# Excel File reading cells value not completed

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, office-interop

I’ve been trying to read in an Excel file using either a DataSet or DataTable.

There is a problem reading theEexcel file. My columns' values are:

```
First Row:   abc def ghi jkl
Second  Row: abc def ghi jkl abc
```

But it reads only the content below (I have checked in debugging):

```
First Row:  abc def ghi jkl
Second Row: abc def ghi     (second row displaying wrong)
```

My connection string:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="FILENAE";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"""
```

What I have already tried:

```
TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text
```

I am using the Interop Library

Comment: Whenever I've had to deal with Excel files I've had great success with ExcelDataReader. If that's an option for you, you should look into it: https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader

Comment: It could be the "Header of the Columns" problem. If you don't mind that no header of column in datatable, then you could turn the "HDR=Yes" to "HDR=No".

Comment: But OLEDB is not a good approach to load Excel Data, in my personal opinion. I have used OLEDB in some WinForm cases, it was a nightmare to deploy the app on other machine, most of time I have installed other add-on on the machine. I recommend to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, To avoid IO and efficient problem of Interop, you could load Excel data in a array object first then close the excel connection. Then trans the data in this array object to a datatable. The benefit of this approach is that you don't need other add on.

Comment: @Kuo-hsuanHsu You should also mention the drawbacks when advising to use the Interop: 1. Office must be installed and licensed on the machine; 2. Not advisable for a server environment; 3. Slower than OLEDB (or Open XML SDK)

Comment: Truely those drawbacks that Cindy has mentioned above. And does the "HDR = No" not work?

Comment: May be not the solution at all, but there's one interesting way: save the required worksheet as XML and read it with XElement (or XmlElement - whatever fits you).